# Module "pretty-format" has no exported member 'CompareKeys'

Tags: javascript

import type { CompareKeys } from 'pretty-format';

```
../node_modules/jest-matcher-utils/node_modules/jest-diff/build/types.d.ts:7:15 - error TS2305: Module '"pretty-format"' has no exported member 'CompareKeys'.
enter code here
7 import type { CompareKeys } from 'pretty-format';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

"jest-matcher-utils": "^27.5.1"

"pretty-format": "^27.0.2"

Comment: I think it should be with lowercase C.
import type { compareKeys } from 'pretty-format';

Answer (score 0):

This issue was in dependency of dependency and I am not using this "pretty-format"

I just installed this and its helped

```
yarn add jest-matcher-utils@^28.1.0
```

Hope it will save days of debugging to someone.